# Malloc a 2D array possible size overflow

Tags: c, malloc

Here is a simplified version of my program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

    char **words, **nwords;

    int x;
    words = malloc(sizeof *words * 1000);
    if (words) {
        for (x = 0; x < 20; x++) {
            words[x] = malloc(sizeof *words[x] * 1); 
        }   
    }   

    nwords = malloc(sizeof *nwords * 1000);
    if (nwords) {
        for (x = 0; x < 20; x++) {
            nwords[x] = malloc(sizeof(char) * 200);
            //nwords[x] = "123456789012345"; // works correctly
            nwords[x] = "1234567890123456"; // garbage
        }   
    }   

    int i;
    for (i=0; i<10;i++) {
        sprintf(words[i],"%s",nwords[i]);
    }   

    for (i=0; i<10;i++) {
        printf("\n words[%d] = %s",i,words[i]);
    }   

    return 0;
}
```

If the number of characters in nwords[x] increases beyond 15, then final `printf` starts printing weird concatenated output. (See line `nwords[x] = "1234567890123456"; // garbage`) Why is this so? I gave to it 200 character worth memory using malloc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With this statement

```
words[x] = malloc(sizeof *words[x] * 1);
```

you allocate a single character to `words[x]`. Then you do

```
sprintf(words[i],"%s",nwords[i]);
```

which writes more than one character to `words[i]`.

---

Also, with

```
nwords[x] = malloc(sizeof(char) * 200);
nwords[x] = "1234567890123456"; // garbage
```

you first make `nwords[x]` point to some memory you allocate off the heap, then directly afterwards you make it point to a string literal instead. You possibly want either

```
nwords[x] = malloc(sizeof(char) * 200);
strcpy(nwords[x], "1234567890123456");
```

or

```
nwords[x] = strdup("1234567890123456");
```

Comment: @user13107 Because *undefined behavior*. When behavior is undefined, it can *seem* to work sometimes.

Comment: Thanks. If instead of 2D char array I had 2D int array, can I assign values using `=` operator instead of `strcpy`?

Comment: @user13107 First you need to allocate the second dimension, but then just assignment of the actual values.